# How to sum values in Java Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am reading an  input file:

```
Tuesday 50.40000000000001
Friday 35.5
Wednesday 51.5
Friday 46.49999999999999
Thursday 47.89999999999999
Friday 42.60000000000001
Tuesday 48.900000000000006
Thursday 47.300000000000026
Thursday 50.90000000000001
Wednesday 52.1
Monday 52.50000000000001
Thursday 53.1
Tuesday 49.000000000000014
Monday 36.900000000000006
Wednesday 46.70000000000001
Thursday 51.30000000000002
Monday 49.99999999999998
```

I want to filter each day and sum up all its values - i.e add all Monday values, then Tuesdays and so on. How can I do it in Java. I tried to use a hashmap with code bellow but I was not able to do it. I need help please.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("weekly.txt")));
     String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String splittedWord []= line.split("\\s+");
            String key = splittedWord[0];

            map.put(key, new ArrayList<Double>());

            for(int i=1;i<splittedWord.length;i++){
                double temp = Double.parseDouble(splittedWord[i]);      
                if(map.containsKey(key)){
                    map.get(key).add(temp); // adding keys and values to the encode hashmap O(n)
                }

            } 
        }
        System.out.println("The size of encodeMap is " + map.size());

         Iterator test = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (test.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)test.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());

                test.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException             
            }           
    }
```

Comment: where is your map defined? What is it defined as?

Comment: private static HashMap<String,List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Double>>();  This is at the top.

Comment: well I would change it to `HashMap<String, Double>` and then `if(!map.containsKey(key)){ map.put(key, temp);} else {map.get(key) + temp}`

Comment: Thanks man. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a requirement to store all values for each day, change your code as follows:

```
 private static HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, temp);
    } else {
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + temp);
    }
```